# Ruby source code analyzer (something like pylint)

Tags: ruby, code-analysis, static-analysis

Does Ruby have any tools along the lines of [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) for analyzing source code for errors and simple coding standards?

It would be nice if it could be integrated with [cruisecontrolrb](http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/) for continuous integration.

Or does everyone write such good tests that they don't need source code checkers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I reviewed a bunch of Ruby tools that are available here

http://devver.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/ruby-tools-roundup/

most of the tools were mentioned by webmat, but if you want more information I go pretty in depth with examples.

I also highly recommend using Metric-Fu it gives you a on gem/plugin install of 3 of the more popular tools and is built with cruisecontrolrb integration in mind.

The creator has a great post that should help get you up and running in no time.

http://jakescruggs.blogspot.com/2008/04/dead-simple-rails-metrics-with-metricfu.html

There has been a lot of activity in Ruby tools lately which I think is a good sign of a growing and maturing language.

Comment: I will also take a good look at reek -  http://silkandspinach.net/2008/09/23/reek-a-code-smells-detector-for-ruby/ suggested by webmat. Would you consider including it in your answer for others?

Comment: Holy crap! That tools roundup looks pretty comprehensive. I'll have to check it out :-) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: your links aren't valid any longer have you updated them to a new blog

Comment: @sayth I browsed through their webpage and found the new permalink. I updated the post.

Answer (score 10):

Check these out:

- on Ruby Inside, [an article presenting Towelie, Flay and Simian](http://www.rubyinside.com/3-tools-for-drying-your-ruby-code-1305.html), all tools to find code duplication

  - [Towelie](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2008/10/verbatim-how-to-find-patterns-in-code.html)
  - [flay](http://ruby.sadi.st/Flay.html)
  - [Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/) (a more general tool that supports Ruby among other languages)
- [reek](http://silkandspinach.net/2008/09/23/reek-a-code-smells-detector-for-ruby/): a code smell detector for Ruby
- [Roodi](http://www.martyandrews.net/blog/2008/09/roodi_checkstyle_for_ruby.html): checks the style of your Ruby code
- [flog](http://ruby.sadi.st/Flog.html): a code complexity analyzer
- [rcov](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?rcov): will give you a [C0](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?rcov#l15) (if I remember correctly) code coverage analysis. But be careful though. 100% coverage is very costly and doesn't mean perfect code.
- [heckle](http://ruby.sadi.st/Heckle.html): changes your code in subtle manners and runs your test suite to see if it catches it. Brutal :-)

Since they're all command-line tools they can all be integrated simply as cc.rb tasks. Just whip out your regex skillz to pick the important part of the output.

I recommend you first try them out by hand to see if they play well with your codebase and if you like the info they give you. Once you find a few that give you value, then spend time integrating them in your cc.

Comment: Great answer thank you, reek looks very interesting, sorry I chose the other answer, the blog post he referenced was very thorough.

Answer (score 5):

One recently-updated interesting-looking tool is [Ruby Object Oriented Design Inferometer](http://roodi.rubyforge.org/) - roodi for short. It's at v1.3.0, so I'm guessing it's fairly mature.

I haven't tried it myself, because my code is of course already beyond reproach (hah).

As for test coverage (oh dear, I haven't tried this one either) there's [rcov](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/rails_rcov)

Also (look, I am definitely going to try some of these today. One at least) you might care to take a look at [flog and flay](http://ruby.sadi.st/Ruby_Sadist.html) for another style checker and a refactoring candidate finder.

Comment: And don't forget to heckle your tests!  The resources in this answer will really whip your project into shape...  Especially with the release of Flay this weekend; impressive stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the built-in warnings you can enable with a quick:

```
ruby -w
```

Or setting the global variable $VERBOSE to true at any point.

Answer (score 2):

[Code metrics](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics) on ruby toolbox website.

Answer (score 1):

[Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) is a widely-used static code analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

I just released Excellent which implements several checks on Ruby code. It combines roodi, reek and flog and also adds some Rails specific checks:

```
gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
sudo gem install simplabs-excellent
```

May be helpful...