# Is there a static analysis tool for Python, Ruby, Sql, Cobol, Perl, and PL/SQL?

Tags: python, ruby, plsql, static-analysis, cobol

I am looking for a static analysis tool for Python, Ruby, Sql, Cobol, Perl, PL/SQL, SQL similar to find bugs and check style. I am looking for calculating the line count, identify bugs during the development, and enforcing coding standard.

Answer (score 10):

Perl has [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic.pm) (and [perlcritic.com](http://perlcritic.com/))

Comment: It worked pretty well for me; it found some archaisms in my code which I’d been copy/pasting since before they were archaic.

Comment: @Flash - curious as to what they were?

Comment: Funny you should ask yesterday; I think they were violations at Palm, from my BBEdit Perl stationery, of “128. Use … the three-argument form of open.  This variant was introduced in Perl 5.6 and is more robust that the older two- argument version, which is susceptible to very rare, but subtle, failures.”  I’d originally written the code in the last millennium; nothing is so permanent as sample code…

Answer (score 4):

I use [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) and [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint) as Python code checkers. However it seems that they get buggy when you use some modules (e.g., `socket` or `pygame`, IIRC).

Comment: Both Perl:Critic and Pylint looks very good for Python.. Which would be the best choice?

Comment: @unknown: Well, the one that says Perl is no good for Python :)

Comment: +1 for pychecker and pylint. I prefer pylint.

Comment: Thank you Brian and chris for our suggestion

Comment: +1 for pylint.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a version for 3.x yet.

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby, you're probably best served looking at this previous SO question:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286564/can-anyone-recommend-a-ruby-source-code-analyzer-something-like-pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286564)

which seems pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0):

I use Pylint for Python which was nicely [integrated into Komodo by Brandon Corfman](http://mysite.verizon.net/bcorfman/2007/02/komodo-hacks-integrating-pylint.html) (if ActiveState's Komodo is your thing).

Answer (score 0):

Sonar has a [PL/SQL plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/plugins/) that is based on Toad CodeXpert code analyzer.

Comment: I am looking for a open source plugin's preferably

Answer (score 0):

See various static analysis tools from [Semantic 
Designs](http://www.semanticdesigns.com).

These cover standard metrics for Java, C# and COBOL.   There are also tools to detect duplicate code (clones) for many languages, including Python, Java, PL/SQL (from your list).

Finally, there is a style checker (coding standards checks) for COBOL (with optional Eclipse plugin) that offers refactoring support to fix some of the style errors.