# Is there a stylecop equivalent for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, stylecop

StyleCop is a tool that analyzes C# source code to enforce a set of style and consistency rules.

Is there anything similar for the Ruby language?

Answer (score 0):

Are these questions and their answers of any use?

- [Can anyone recommend a Ruby source code analyzer (something like pylint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286564)
- [Is there a static analysis tool for Python, Ruby, Sql, Cobol, Perl, and PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956104/is-there-a-static-analysis-tool-for-python-ruby-sql-cobol-perl-and-pl-sql)