# Is there an alternative to reek

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://rubygems.org/gems/reek Not sure if this is in active development, is there an alternative to the `reek` tool.

Comment: Check these - http://devver.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/ruby-tools-roundup/. Also, any issues that you found with `reek`, I'm not sure, they haven't had a release after 2010. but the version I downloaded from the site works good enough for me.

Comment: You may also have a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286564/can-anyone-recommend-a-ruby-source-code-analyzer-something-like-pylint

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics

Comment: Just want to add that as of 2013-11-25 it is still in active development.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop)
2. [Rubycritic](https://github.com/whitesmith/rubycritic)
3. [Hound](https://github.com/thoughtbot/hound)
4. [Ruby-lint](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint)
5. [Tailor](https://github.com/turboladen/tailor)